# mathspec and \RequirePackage{amsmath} error

Tags: xetex, amsmath, mathspec

In my package, I request amsmath with `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`, resulting in this basic setup:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\RequirePackage{amsmath} % part of another package, \usepackage{...}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

This leads to the error

> Package mathspec Error: 'amsmath' must be loaded earlier than 'mathspec'.

at the 2nd request for amsmath, although amsmath is already loaded.

I could, of course load my package before mathspec. However, a user of my package has the problem that he uses a template and cannot load packages before  `mathspec`, only after it.

1. I'd consider this a bug. The error should not be raised when amsmath is already loaded. Do you agree?
2. Is there a way I could change my package (replace `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`) to avoid this error?

Comment: Do not use `minimal`, neither for minimal examples nor real documents.

Comment: This is hardcoded in `mathspec`. A veryy simple and basic solution would be to test if `amsmath` is already loaded and else set a warning if loaded later. I would consider this a bug (cannot call this feature) and reach out to the package maintainer.